# apply() got an unexpected keyword argument 'raw'

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I get `TypeError: apply() got an unexpected keyword argument 'raw'` when I run the following code in pandas 0.22.0.

```
import pandas as pd

def my_func(x, b):
   y = x.diff().abs().sum()
   return b**y

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})
df.rolling(2).apply(lambda x: my_func(x, 0.1), raw=False)
```

When I remove `raw=False` it complains `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'diff'`. Based on the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), the default behavior should be equivalent to `raw=False`. I would also like to add that I do not have issues with something like `df.apply(lambda x: sum(x), raw=False)`.

Can someone help me understand this behavior? I also appreciate any thoughts on how I can possibly fix it.

I do not have issues with the same line of code with newer versions of pandas but upgrading pandas is not currently an option.

Comment: You should be looking at the docs for [`Rolling.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.core.window.Rolling.apply.html#pandas.core.window.Rolling.apply), not `Dataframe.apply`.

Comment: If you upgrade Pandas, `Rolling.apply` will have `raw`.